# Trouble with template rendering in Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I worked through a very good tutorial (Django Girls).  Works perfectly on Django's local server.

It was also working perfectly on Heroku, so long as the web pages were static.  But once I used a template to fill in three simple items, it does not render them as it does on the local Django server.

I have been through installing/using whitenoise, following the advice at Heroku's site, etc., etc. All that did was cause the admin console to look pretty again (it had been rendering like a web page with very low bandwidth - no actual graphic oomph, just text with underlines).  So, the use of whitenoise seems to have worked there.

But on my home-brew page, when I look at the HTML that gets sent to the browser from Heroku, it has all the various  tags, etc., but none of the content.

As I said this is od since it works fine on the local server.  I have tried changing the {% include static %} tp {% include staticfiles %}, I have run 'collectstatics' successfully, I have inserted all the code that whitenoise and heroku recommend.

The template is pretty simple:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
  <title> My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1><a href="/">My Test Blog</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="post">
              <h2<a href="">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
              <div class="date"><p>published: {{post.published_date }}</p></div>
              <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the calling code passes in a good dict, since it renders just fine locally.  However, what comes out of the remote implementation on Heroku has 'stripped' much, but not all, of the info from the template. It looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/blog.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1><a href="/">My Test Blog</a></h1>
  </div>
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you care to see it, here is what comes out of the local web server, all done exactly right:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/blog.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1><a href="/">My Test Blog</a></h1>
  </div>
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="post">
        <h2<a href="">Here is post 1</a></h2>
        <div class="date"><p>published: Aug. 21, 2017, 4:44 p.m. </p></div>
            <p>This is the etxt for the first post</p>
          </div>

      <div class="post">
        <h2<a href="">2nd post</a></h2>
        <div class="date"><p>published: Aug. 21, 2017, 4:44 p.m. </p></div>
            <p>If one is not enough, here is #2...</p>
          </div>

      <div class="post">
        <h2<a href="">3rd post</a></h2>
        <div class="date"><p>published: Aug. 21, 2017, 4:44 p.m. </p></div>
            <p>And yet one more....</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, it gets the same calling code, but here it is if you want to know:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request) :
    posts =     Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request,'blog/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

Usually one suspects version inconsistencies, but using requirements.txt as well as virtualenv would seem to eliminate most of those issues.  The info looks identical from the admin console, so it is a bit peculiar since one would suspect that Django itself would not have wildly different behavior on the two platforms, especially after going through all the steps Heroku gives for making use of whitenoise, and since Heroku otherwise has no problem collecting up statics or running the code - it certainly finds the template but fails to fill it in.

Comment: It's pretty hard to troubleshoot code we can't see. Please read [ask].

Comment: Do you get any errors in your Heroku Logs, or your browser console?